# Axis not displaying in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

!wget -O FuelConsumption.csv https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses- 
data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/FuelConsumptionCo2.csv

df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")
df.head()

df1 = df[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']]
df1.head(9)

plt.scatter(df1.ENGINESIZE , df1.CO2EMISSIONS , color = "black")
plt.xlabel=("enginesize")
plt.ylabel=("emission")
plt.show()
```

when i try to run this code i get scatter graph without axis label.
how can i get axis label if anyone can assist me ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the label names to `xlabel` and `ylabel`.
If it's throwing error - `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` then restart the ipython kernel

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")
df.head()

df1 = df[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']]
df1.head(9)

plt.scatter(df1.ENGINESIZE , df1.CO2EMISSIONS , color = "black")
plt.xlabel("enginesize")
plt.ylabel("emission")
plt.show()
```

[image]